# List(Log)Plot with "high" resolution results in various warnings, e.g. BinCounts::step

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

Here is some very odd behavior from [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html).

So if I want to plot a function using [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html), I can specify the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) in either `{min,max}` or `{max,min}` format.

```
LogPlot[x^6, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10^5}]
LogPlot[x^6, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {10^5, 10^-9}]
```

[image]

So now I try to do the same thing with `ListLogPlot` I encounter an error:

```
list = Table[{x, x^6}, {x, 0, 5, .01}];
Grid[{{ListLogPlot[list, PlotRange -> {10^-9, 10^5}],
   ListLogPlot[list, PlotRange -> {10^5, 10^-9}]}}]
```

[image]
[image]

Obviously the problem can be fixed by putting the `PlotRange` specification in order, but it can also be fixed by changing the x-coordinate grid spacing.

```
list = Table[{x, x^6}, {x, 0, 5, .02}];
ListLogPlot[list, PlotRange -> {10^5, 10^-9}]
```

[image]

That's weird.  Weirder still - the more plots you try to show at the same time, the coarser you need to make the grid spacing to avoid the error.  For two lists, we need $\Delta x>0.03$

```
(list = Table[{x, x^6}, {x, 0, 5, #}];
   ListLogPlot[{list, {#1, 10 #2} & @@@ list}, 
    PlotRange -> {10^5, 10^-9}]) & /@ {.02, .03}
```

[image]

Adding a third list, it is fine with $\Delta x>0.03$, but for a fourth list, $\Delta x>0.05$ is needed.

What is behind this odd behavior in `ListLogPlot`?

Comment: @JasonB Thanks for editing and bringing it right to the issue